# What was Herman Munsters' role when he fought in World War II?

Tags: warfare, history, the-munsters

I was researching the Munsters as I build a Lego Munsters diorama for Emerald City ComiCon. According to [Herman Munster's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Munster) page, he fought in World War II.

> Herman married Lily, and eventually the couple and Grandpa (Lily's father) moved to America, where **Herman joined the U.S. Army, fighting in World War II**.

I don't recall seeing an episode featuring Herman either in the Army, or fighting in World War II. 
What was Herman Munsters' role when he fought in World War II? It's stated he fought. Did he see action?

Comment: [In WWII, the ratio of combat soldiers to support personnel was around 1:4 (4 support to 1 combat).](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Military-Policy-Weapons-346/2009/9/Support-Troop-Combat-Troop.htm) So even though Herman may have *served,* there's a good chance he was in a support role.

Comment: @JoeL the quote does say "fighting" though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Season 1 Episode 6 titled "Low Cal Munster", Herman wants to attend a reunion of his U.S. Army outfit.  Around minute 3:30 we get dialog between the Munster family about his time in the Army.

1. In what war did Herman serve?

> Herman: "This is the first time in 20 years the guys in my old outfit
>   are getting together."

The show was set contemporary in the mid 1960s, so that would place his service at least at the end of World War II in the mid 1940s.  It could even be earlier than that, since the show does not indicate whether Herman and his Army buddies had reunions or get-togethers after their enlistment ended before the 20-year gap.

2. As for what role he had in the war, we get limited information but he was on the front lines:

> Herman: "When I get up out of that foxhole, the enemy would take one
>   look at me in this uniform and run.  Come to think of it, a lot of our
>   guys used to look at me and run too."

Comment: Nice. That works for me. +1 and a cigar.